# Flask does not give me errors

Tags: python, flask

this is when i start my web app,

```
 * Serving Flask app "ucp.py" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 241-130-592
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

this is what it display on the browser:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

this is my `__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_manager

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = 'login'

app.debug=True

from app import routes, autoload
```

This is my .flaskenv

```
FLASK_APP=ucp.py
FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

Debugging is active, but I'm not getting it

Comment: Your app is probably logging an exception somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You might be implementing Config wrong, try:

app.config.from_object('config')

where 'config' is a configuration file.